# remove elements from the jQuery object from within a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I think I have mistaken some fundamentals here, because I think this should work. I am trying to to through the child `p` and `div` elements of the matched set, and remove those which fail to meet the required wordcount from the matched set.

I have tested the `wordCount` plugin, and the `if` statement it is being used it, and all seems to be working fine, but my element is not being removed from the matched set.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        textBlocks: function(count){
            var JQ_Object = $(this);
            if(!count) count = 100;
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).find("p, div").each(function(){
                    if($(this).wordCount()<count){
                        var x = $(this);
                        JQ_Object.not(x);   
                    };
                });
                return JQ_Object;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

---

Here is the wordCount plugin, just in case you wondered:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        wordCount: function(){
            return $(this).html().split(" ").length;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Wordcount should probably be `$(this).text().split(' ').length` not `.html()` otherwise you're expanding markup tags as well (though it's be more accurate to go down the node list looking for `nodeType==3`.)

Comment: You're creating a new JQ_Object in the internal each, so I'm not sure if it would modify the original JQ_Object. I'm not 100% on that though. Try JQ_Object.not(this).

Comment: I don't see what you mean. `JQ_Object` is defined before the each

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes... see fiddle for working example and code for comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/8PXpt/

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.extend({
        wordCount: function (){
            //Don't need $(this), this already refers to the jQuery object
            //Always trim .html() and .text() when using .split()
            //May want to use .text() instead of .html() - I leave that to you
            return $.trim(this.html()).split(' ').length;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);



(function ($){
    $.fn.extend({
        textBlocks: function (count){
            var collection = this;

            //Check that a number was passed
            //"50" would break your extension
            if(typeof count !== 'number') {
                count = 100;
            }

            //Removed $('div, p') - this should be part of your call
            //See ready function below
            this.each(function (){

                if ($(this).wordCount() < count){
                    //This could be double assignment
                                    //but better safe than sorry
                    collection = collection.not(this);   
                };

            });

            //Return what is left (what passed)
            return collection ;
       }
    });
})(jQuery);


$(function() {
   //Here is where you define your selector... in your case 'div, p'
   $('div, p').textBlocks(2);
});
```

Comment: this works great, but why can't I use the `find` method from within the plugin? This how I would like it to behave.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz there is no need to use `find()` as the selector will pass it the collection of `p` and `div` elements. If you want to only include elements that are in a particular `div` you can use `$('#foo').find('p,div').textBlocks(100);`

Comment: I understand that, but the point it automation. You provide a containing div, the plugin does the rest

Comment: Code re-use is a big part of leaving the selector outside of your plugin.  If you want to re-use this plug-in you don't want to have specific implementation details inside of it.  jQuery allows a clean separation here, I'd take advantage of that ability.  I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$(this).remove()` rather than `JQ_Object.not(x);`

I think `.not()` removes them from the selection rather than from the HTML... unless that's what you're trying to do

Comment: Indeed, I believe you want `remove()`. And I believe `not()` returns the list exempt of the excludes, not just "pop" them off the current object. i.e. the different of `this = this.not()` vs. `this.not()`

Comment: remove takes the element out of the DOM, not the matched set.

Comment: ok, your question didn't make clear whether you wanted to remove it from the DOM or the matched set

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new JQ_Object in the internal each, so I'm not sure if it would modify the original JQ_Object. I'm not 100% on that though. Try JQ_Object.not(this).

This assumes, however, that .each is synchronous, which I'd hope it isn't. If that's the case, you'd need to make use of jQuery's while function.

This should give you the desired result, but I'd be wary each being asynchronous.

```
return $(this).find("p, div").each(function(){
    if($(this).wordCount()<count){
       JQ_Object.not(this);
    };
});
```

EDIT:

I'm not to sure about the above code. What I'd do is use a callback. This assumes a callback is passed in to your plugin.

```
$(this).find("p, div").each(function(){
    if($(this).wordCount()<count){
       JQ_Object.not(this);
    };
}).when(function () {
    callback(JQ_Object);
});
```

Comment: This returned the element I want to remove, for some reason

Comment: I added an example using callbacks.